# Cannot change Panel.BackColor on Enter event

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I have a bunch of `UserControl`s one inside others and at the top of them there is a panel and some other controls around. What I want to do is change that panel's backcolor.

If I set a color from the designer, the color is displayed correctly.

If I set it through code it doesn't change.

At the same point I set the backcolor of the panel I also set its parent borderColor which changes correctly.

After changing the color I tried `Update` and `Invalidate` on the panel but nothing happened.
The container of the panel has the focus, don't know if that helps.

What blocks the panel from changing its color?

```
Color highlightedColor = Color.Blue;
panelControl.BorderColor = highlightedColor;
indicatorPanel.BackColor = highlightedColor;
```

Although I use DevExpress, I've also tried with winforms's panel. Same behavior.

**edit**

There are more that I can't change. Just tried a backcolor for a label. From the designer changes from code doesn't.

The code runs on `Enter` event

**edit2**

The problem relies on the event I call the code. I tried using a button and it works. So there must be something wrong when doing stuff on `Enter` event.

Comment: Where this code runs? Inside what event? If you put it inside button click event does it work?

Comment: Nice suggestion. I tried from a button, and it works! Any idea why it doesn't work on Enter event?

Comment: Some things can't be changed during certain events, for example trying to hide a form in its Load event won't really work. Personally to overcome this I always used a Timer not bothering to look for "real" solution. It works, but not really elegant..

Comment: Ass seen here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.enter.aspx It IS POSSIBLE to change colors inside the `Enter` event

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to call `Update` on the `UserControl` itself, not the containers that I'm changing their colors.

Comment: Somewhat weird, but glad you found the real solution. :)

Comment: Not a solution, only a band-aid.  Don't write loops in UI code, painting only occurs when the UI thread is idle.  You'll have a lot more trouble if you keep using band-aids like this.